# 'scoop list' on PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, scoop

When I execute the command '**scoop list**' on PowerShell I get this reply:

> **There aren't any apps installed.**

How do I fix this to show all installed software?

Comment: Not everything, but this will get you a partial list `gcim -Class Win32_Product | select name, version`

Comment: Is scoop installed on your pc?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio if Scoop isn't installed, it would give the error `scoop : The term 'scoop' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: Have you installed any app using scoop?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio nope. And I don't want to install nothing with it. I just want it to list all the software that is already installed in the machine.

Comment: Scoop doesn't do that, @Twinsen (winget does). As ReddyLutonadio said in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1699680/358572): scoop only lists packages it installed.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the message because you have not installed any package/app using scoop. As far as I know, scoop only list the packages that it installed.

If you want to list packages via a package manager, you can either use chocolatey (with the command `choco list -li`) or winget (from Microsoft). You will need to install them first. There are other package managers if you are not in the two mentioned, just google them.